# How to estimate cov(x1,x2) via R code, if we know x2=rho*x1,x1~N(0.127,0.053), x2~N(0.106,0.09)

Tags: r, dependencies, simulation, covariance

I have generated x1 and x2 via rnorm() function and the estimation seems to be unstable for limited samples. Therefore, I wonder how to calculate the cov(x1,x2) by the formula or the simulation method.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your real problem? What do you want to do with cov(x1,x2)?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have a spatial difference in differences modeling, like "y=....+alpha3*D*T+alpha4*weight*D*T" ,, where alpha4 = alpha3*rho (average direct treatment effect:alpha3; average indirect treatment effect:alpha4*weight). Then I have trouble in calculating the variance of ATE Var(ATE)=Var(alpha3)+weight^2*Var(alpha4)+2*weight*cov(alpha3,alpha4). mainly about the estimation of cov(alpha3,alpha4). The question originated from equation 13 in the article (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0966692318301820)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to that paper over my university. I assume that alpha3 is x1 and alpha4 is x2? If that is the case, please note that there is something wrong with your given means and variances of x1 and x2. You can see that in my answer. That may be your "real problem".

Comment: Thank you for your advice. You might assume that the rho is a constant term. However, in that paper, the rho parameter should be an autoregressive variable. I know how to approximate the E(rho) and Var(rho) by the second Taylor expansion but the estimation of cov(alpha3, alpha4) is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you have x2 = rho * x1. The definition of cov(x1,x2) is E[(x1 - E[x1])(x2 - E[x2])]. Therefore:

cov(x1,x2) = E[(x1-E[x1])(x2-E[x2])] = E[(x1-E[x1])(rho* x1-E[rho* x1])] = E[(x1-E[x1])(rho*(x1-E[x1]))] = E[(x1-E[x1])(x1-E[x1])] * rho = rho * E[(x1-E[x1])^2] = rho * Var(x1)

Thus cov(x1,x2) = rho * Var(x1).

However, there is an error in your question.
You say E[x1] = 0.127 ans E[x2] = 0.106, so since x1 and x2 are normal distributed, rho = 0.106/0.127 < 1. The variance of x2 is given by Var(x2) = Var(rho*x1) = rho^2 * Var(x1) < 1 * Var(x1) = Var(x1). But you have Var(x2) > Var(x1)???

You can see that here:

```
> a = rnorm(100000, 0.127, sqrt(0.053)) #generate some samples
> b = 0.106/0.127 * a
> cov(a,b) #empirical correlation
[1] 0.04406267
> 0.106/0.127 * var(a) #expected correlation
[1] 0.04406267
> mean(a)
[1] 0.1276717
> mean(b) #mean of a and b is correct
[1] 0.1065606
> var(a)
[1] 0.05279207
> var(b) #but the variance not
[1] 0.03677672
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess you might regard the rho parameter as a constant term but unfortunately the rho parameter should be an autoaggressive parameter (or calculate as a random variable giving x1 and x2). The question originated from equation 13 in the article (sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0966692318301820).

Comment: Sorry but I do not have much knowledge about autoregression. That rho is dependent on x1 and x2 is not enough information for me. E.g., it makes a difference whether rho=x1 or rho=x1^2. I think you should ask your question again, but redrafted, on this site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/.